# "statsd" prefix on data when using Telegraf with StatsD

Tags: influxdb, statsd

I am using Telegraf as a server to collect StatsD data from Python and send it to InfluxDB. However, the name values I receive in InfluxDB have the prefix "statsd_". How can I remove it?

In python I do:

```
ctr_name  = 'foo'
client = statsd.StatsClient('MY_DOMAIN.com', 8125)
client.incr(ctr_name, 1)
```

And then in InfluxDB I see:

```
> show measurements
name: measurements
------------------
name
statsd_foo
```

Answer (score -1):

By default, the statsd python package [does not put a prefix](http://statsd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html#statsclient) in front of your measurements.

Below is the default

```
client = statsd.StatsClient('MY_DOMAIN.com', 8125, prefix=None)
```

I am pretty sure you set `prefix="statsd"` in your actual code

The problem does not seem to come from the statsd plugin configuration in  Telegraf since it doesnt offer to prefix all measurements with a string constant. See [here](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/tree/master/plugins/inputs/statsd)

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the case, I don't have any prefix set in the way you described. Also, it doesn't seem to be Telegraf either, because I am now testing with PHP and no prefix is added. I guess it must come from the configuration of the Python plugin... But nevermind, I just need to use it for PHP :)

Comment: that's weird, don't really know what is going on there. If you ever get more debug data feel free to update the question

Comment: this is wrong; telegraf will prefix all metrics with the name of the input plugin by default.